# .Blade.php page doesn't work with localhost but with php artisan server it's work

Tags: php, laravel, apache, localhost

Hey guys am new to **laravel** and when i create route veiw to .blade.php page it's doesn't work with **apache2** **localhost** even with virtual host but if i run `php artisan server` it works fine. 
Here's My code :
**In web.php file in routes directory:**

```
Route::get('users', function(){

return view('users');});
```

**In resources/view i have users.blade.php it contain:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome From Users View</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I open **localhost/project/public** it will work and show me laravel default page.
But if I run **localhost/project/public/users** it won't work. 
 But When i type in terminal `php artisan ser` and go to **127.0.0.1:8080** 'as he told me then' **/users** it will work just fine and show me the content of **users.blade.php**

Some info about the enviroment :
**Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon 5.4.12**
and **Apache2** local server without xampp or lampp 
All the extentions are installed

Answer (score 0):

Your localhost server is entirely different from that provided by `php artisan serve`

If you are using xampp/wamp or any other related software, you cant access the urls that way.

Using the `php artisan serve` , your base url is `127.0.0.1:8000`

In your web.php this code that you wrote:

```
Route::get('users', function(){
return view('users');});
```

It means that if you access the url `127.0.0.1:8080/users` it will display the view file called `users.blade.php`

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#basic-routing)

With that said. You should not access it via the localhost url.

Comment: I only applied what the one does in the laravel course he can access via localhost                by the way am using pure apache2 and mysql without app like xampp or lamp

Comment: Try restarting your apache2 server and try the ```localhost/project/public/users``` url again.

Comment: same thing.... [link](https://ibb.co/n8Mjc7R)

Comment: From the image, I see that you are trying to access it via ```localhost/public/users```. It should be ```localhost/project_name/public/users``` unless you installed laravel to your root folder

Comment: No man it's `localhost/project_name/public/users` [photo1](https://ibb.co/0mqPgn6) [photo2](https://ibb.co/gvxypLr)